# Chopping audio over bluetooth with PulseAudio

Tags: audio, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I have an issue with a Raspberry Pi 3B+ and audio over bluetooth, it is configured with PulseAudio and BlueZ to connect my phone on the Pi, it works great but there is minor audio cuts (less than 0.5s) every 2-3 minutes.
To be sure that this is a bluetooth or PulseAudio problem I played a local music (aplay cmd) without any problem.

I add "tsched=0" in /etc/pulse/default.pa otherwise the audio is very crackling :

```
### Automatically load driver modules depending on the hardware available
.ifexists module-udev-detect.so
load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
.else
### Use the static hardware detection module (for systems that lack udev support)
load-module module-detect
.endif
```

I tried to change some settings in /etc/pulse/daemon.conf like high-priority, realtime-scheduling, resample-method, default-sample-rate and so on but none was noticeable.

But there is something strange: if I kill PulseAudio and restart it (pulseaudio -k then pulseaudio -D) the audio is great for a long time with no chopping until the Pi reboot or after a pause.

Also, I'm not sure if this is related but there is some logs when streaming bluetooth audio:

```
bluealsa[530]: /usr/bin/bluealsa: Adapter not available: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_9C_2E_A1_CE_CE_F8/fd1
pulseaudio[1310]: Configured latency of 200.00 ms is smaller than minimum latency, using minimum instead
pulseaudio[1310]: Cannot set requested sink latency of 145.01 ms, adjusting to 250.00 ms
pulseaudio[1310]: Cannot set requested source latency of 87.66 ms, adjusting to 135.29 ms
pulseaudio[1310]: SBC decoding error (-2)
Bluetooth: hci0: Frame reassembly failed (-84) <--- a lot of lines like this
```

Thanks for reading and I hope you can help me.

UPDATE:

It seems that the Raspberry Pi bluetooth module causes this issue, so I have solved this by using only BlueZ (no more PulseAudio) and plug a bluetooth dongle which works a lot better.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like the known issue. You might want to follow some of the issues that are open around this topic:

https://github.com/Arkq/bluez-alsa/issues/60

https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1552

https://github.com/balenalabs/balena-sound/issues/62